# Replacing any values within the attributes of xml which has prefixes using powershell

Tags: powershell

Can somebody help me in this. I'm competely new to powershell. When I try modify value between the attribute "`<sind:Integration>`" am getting an error as undeclared prefix. I need to change any values between the attribute "`<sind:Integration>`"

```
<server>
<sind:service>
<sind:Integration>test</sind:Integration>
</sind:service>
</server>
```

I have tried multiple ways and I'm getting errors. I'm expecting a solution for this using only PowerShell without any libraries.

Comment: The prefixes are called XML namespaces, and can be managed with standard XML methods. No 3rd party libraries are needed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please include what you have tried and the error you are having. Here are some articles for you. [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Even though you already have an answer, you will have much more success in your future question by adhering to these principles.

Answer (score 0):

Your `xml` miss a namespace.
Add any namespace url `<server xmlns:sind="https://somewhere">`

Then code like this will work.

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<server xmlns:sind="https://somewhere">
<sind:service>
<sind:Integration>test</sind:Integration>
</sind:service>
</server>
"@

$xml.server.service.Integration = "value"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the clarification. this is working fine for 1 occurrence how to do it for multiple occurrences. For eg :$xml = [xml]@"
<server xmlns:sind="https://somewhere">
  <sind:service>
   <sind:Integration>test</sind:Integration>
  </sind:service>
  <sind:service>
   <sind:Integration>test4</sind:Integration>
  </sind:service>
 </server>

"@

Comment: Hi Thanks for the clarification. this is working fine for 1 occurrence how to do it for multiple occurrences. For eg :$xml = [xml]@" <server xmlns:sind="somewhere"> <sind:service> <sind:Integration>test</sind:Integration> </sind:service> <sind:service> <sind:Integration>test4</sind:Integration> </sind:service> </server> "@

Comment: `$xml.server.service | %{ $_.Integration = "value" }`